# PhpStorm double quotes in TypeScript auto import

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm in my project.
PhpStorm auto import adds `import` statements with double quotes instead of single quotes.

Can this behaviour be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation` to `Use <single> quotes <always>`

[image]